# How to transition user to DashboadViewController instead of LoginViewController in AppDelegate, if they are already logged in?

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

I am using facebook SDK for user authentication and would like to not show the "Login Using Facebook" Screen (LoginViewController) if the user is already logged in and has an active FB Session.  I have the following code in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {
    // Whenever a person opens the app, check for a cached session
        if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
            NSLog(@"Found a cached session");
            ...code here not essential to this question...

            // Then redirect them to the main dashboard view
            MainDashboardViewController *mainDashboard = [[MainDashboardViewController alloc] init];
            [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:mainDashboard animated:YES];

            // If there's no cached session, show a login button
        } else {
            ...code here not essential to this question...
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

My question is mainly related to the code that redirects them to the MainDashboardViewController as I am not able to make this work.  To add to this...I might be doing this wrong because this MainDashboardVC is part of a NavigationViewController.  I know that segues are not used for this as it is in the AppDelegate and we are not segueing from one viewController to another.  The flow in the storyboard is:

LoginViewController -> NavigationController -> ProfileViewController -> MainDashboardViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options you can explore here, but I believe the reason this isn't working for you is because you are trying to animate the `MainDashboardViewController` transition before any view has appeared on the screen. Have you tried to set the animated boolean to NO on the `pushViewController` call?

However, I think I would consider a different approach. I would, and have done this for many apps, make the `MainDashboardViewController` your window's `rootViewController`, and then present the LoginViewController as a full-screen model when the user is not logged in. You can do this in the `viewWillAppear` method of the `LoginViewController` using the code below.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL animated)
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]   init];
    [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @miken.mkndev.  Changing the animate to NO did not work.  But I think you are right about the issue.  The console reports this error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoginViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa111d2b770'". Looks like it's not quite clear on which viewController to go to or something.

Comment: Did you try the second solution I mentioned? I've been able todo that solution in many apps without issue. Also, the reason you got the exception is because you cannot call pushViewController on the LoginViewController instance as that is a method of the UINavigationController class.